# What BPMN symbol should I use when a service outside wants a BPMS to run a workflow?

Tags: workflows, modeling, bpmn, bpm

I want to specify in a BMPN model that a workflow starts whenever a specific service outside tells me to. What standard BPMN symbol shall I use for this?

Think of it as a company wants to start a workflow only at night, so it uses an application and that app, at night, sends signals to our BPMS and we have to run the workflow that exists in our BPMS.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat It's not a programming question so I don't get what you mean. There are limited number of symbols in BPMN. I can't try anything! I'm asking if a standard exists for this or not? And if not, what symbol is the most relevant and I should use instead?

Comment: @gnat There are around 40 event symbols in BPMN, and it's sometimes difficult to know which one to chose. I assume that OP has knowledge of BPMN but prefers to ask since, since it would be time consuming to test the symbols one after the other, generate the XML for the BPMS and try it out.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

a conditional start event is suited for this kind of situations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/243310)

Comment: @Christophe I am the author! and I researched and my answer is correct.

Comment: Could you at least present your findings and elaborate how a conditional start may fit the expressed needs? In your narrative you mention an overnight signal to start the things.

Answer (score 2):

In a BPMN diagram, you'd use a "start event" symbol (a white circle with a fine border). A marker in the center of this circle can specify further what kind of event starts the process.

In your case, there are several candidates, and I suppose you're asking because you're hesitating between them:

- timer event  (i.e. every day at 23:00, but here the timing does not seem to be fixed in your BPMS),
- message event (for a message received from a *participant* of the process,  but your other system just tells to start and does not seem tp participate itself to the workflow),
- a signal event (i.e. some other process sends a signal).

Looking at your narrative it should be a signal start event, with a triangle marker:

[image: hollow circle surrounding a hollow triangle]

If deemed useful, this [website](https://camunda.com/bpmn/reference/) provides a quick overview table on all kind of events, with additional explanation on each type.

Comment: That's way off from the answer I wanted. But thank you for your time.  Signals and messages are for processes inside a BPMS. I want to run a workflow when a service OUTSIDE OF MY BPMS wants to. By the way I found my answer and that's a CONDITIONAL START EVENT.